# Lightbox div closes on click event of linkbutton

Tags: asp.net, lightbox

I am using below code to show a div in lightbox:

```
<div id="light" class="white_content"><br>
<asp:Image ID="imgLightBox" alt="" border="0" align="" runat="server"></asp:Image><br /><br>
<div class="sliderRightSideArrow"><br>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbLightNext" CssClass="nextEnable" runat="server" ToolTip="Next" OnClick="lbLightNext_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbLightPrevious" CssClass="previousDisable" value="" runat="server" ToolTip="Previous" OnClick="lbLightPrevious_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a>
```

When I click on any of linkbutton, my lightbox div closed but I want to close it on click of `<a> "Close" </a>` only

Comment: can you show any of those link button, check if any jquery code is associated with them.

Comment: <asp:LinkButton ID="lbLightNext" CssClass="nextEnable" runat="server" ToolTip="Next"
                                    OnClick="lbLightNext_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbLightPrevious" CssClass="previousDisable" value="" runat="server"
                                    ToolTip="Previous" OnClick="lbLightPrevious_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>
                        
                        </div>

Comment: <style>
 .black_overlay{
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: black;
        z-index:1001;
        -moz-opacity: 0.8;
        opacity:.80;
        filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    }
    .white_content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 25%;
        left: 25%;
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
        padding: 16px;
        border: 16px solid orange;
        background-color: white;
        z-index:1002;
        overflow: auto;
    }
</style>

Comment: What plugin are you using to display it? Please provide the jQuery code or a demo on jsfiddle

Comment: no plugin is being used; i am using above inline css in webpart usercontrol

Comment: I think the __LinkButton__ is causing a postback so your page is refreshed; you must provide more code; please post it in tha main question non as comment